# Showing cursor in background console window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a little Windows API task I can't rule out.

I need to make cursor visible in the background console window. I tried using GetConsoleCursorInfo / SetConsoleCursorInfo but bVisible in CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO was already true.

How can do it?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is only visible when the console window is the foreground window.

I suppose you could check if `GetConsoleWindow() != GetForegroundWindow()` with a timer and change the text and/or background color with `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute` when you are not in the foreground if you need some type of visual indicator.